# Can I install a ridge vent on simple truss shed roof (no ridge beam)?

Tags: framing, ventilation, roofing, shed

I am building an 8x12 shed and leaning toward a ridge vent/soffit vents for my ventilation. The gable vents won't really work with the aesthetic on the sides.

I'm building simple trusses using 2x4s and gusset plates. This means that my roof peak is "sharp" (it's going to be 6/12, so I think that means my roof peak angle is 60º).

All of the videos I see for ridge vent installs are on roofs with ridge boards running down the peak. All of these ridge vents appear to be resting on a much "flatter" peak, as the ridge board rounds out the peak a bit.

Will I have any issues installing the ridge vent in this application? I realize I'll be cutting back 1" on each side of the peak for the ventilation, but the rafters will still create a sharp peak every 24".

Or is this just not the way to go for this type of simple shed build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan to cut back the roof sheathing back 1" on either side of the ridge is the way it is done whether the roof is truss or conventional, framed with a ridge pole.

I have seen formed aluminum ridge caps used over this cutout or the fiber mat that allows the regular shingles used for the caps to cover over the matting. The angle of the roof will accommodate either.

When you cut back the sheathing, it really wont be sharp anymore, there will be 3 peaks, 2 of the plywood, 1 of the framing. The only sharp part will be at the ends, if you choose to leave 1' of the sheathing intact for weather proofing at the ends.

Comment: I upvoted because you explained how the sheathing is cut back on each side of the peak AND how the 12” at the each end of the ridge remains for flashing, etc. However, I’d prefer no roof top vents because they give an opportunity for leaks to occur. For such a small building, I’d use soffit vents or vents under the eaves.

Comment: @LeeSam , The most effective way to cool a building is to have the eaves vented like you mention, but to have a vent or vents higher up on the roof for the chimney effect. I did mention the preformed aluminum vents which in my opinion are quite prone to leaking. They do not have a large cover over the cut out, so the vent needs to be bedded in sealant. The joints are every 10', the joint connections can be bad. Vented ridge caps using the breathable base are my preferred method. They do not look to out of place too bad, the coverage is sufficient for weather proofing.